# overiding to_param of a nested attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a perma link for a nested attribute.

For example, look at the links for the answers in SO. I would like to do something similar in rails:

I have `Project` model with multiple `tasks` and I would like to create a perma link to a task.

The task can only viewed with the project, just like Q & A on SO.

Ideally, i would do something like:

```
task_helper.rb:
def GetTaskURL
   project = Project.find(:project_id)
   return project_url(project,:html) + "#" + id
end
```

However, i get a method not found. So it seems the only way is to hard-code it:

`domain.com url + Projects/show/id.html#task.id`

Must be a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use the :anchor option

```
return project_url(project,:format => :html, :anchor => id)
```